# Complex Variables

Tags: trigonometry

I am studying complex variables but I seem to have forgotten basic trig!!
I have sin($\theta$) = $\sqrt3$/$2$ and cos($\theta$)=$-1$/$2$.
I need to find $\theta$ in order to find arg(z).
In my notes $\theta$=$2\pi$/$3$. How did they find this without using a calculator? Was it through triangles? No working was shown for this.

Comment: Recall $\frac{\sin(\theta)}{\cos(\theta)} = \tan(\theta)$.

Comment: I did this and then took the inverse of tan but I didn't get the same answer? I feel like I'm being really silly!

Comment: Oh, keep in kind that we're looking at the second quadrant, not the fourth! Arctangent gives the quadrant $4$ angle.

Comment: If you go plain basic and consult the trig tables, the values that satisfy the sine are $\frac{\pi}{3}$ and $\frac{2\pi}{3}$, for the cosine it is $\frac{2\pi}{3}$ and $\frac{4\pi}{3}$. Conclusion?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation

Comment: Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

If $\sin(\theta) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ and $\cos(\theta) = -\frac{1}{2}$, then $\frac{\sin(\theta)}{\cos(\theta)} = \tan(\theta) = -\sqrt{3}$. Recall that if $\tan(x) = y$, then $y = \begin{cases} \arctan(y)+2\pi k\\ \pi+\arctan(y)+2\pi k\end{cases} = \arctan(y)+\pi k$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Notice that sine is positive and cosine is negative, so the angle must be in quadrant $2$. However, arctangent returns an angle in quadrant $1$ (for positive arguments) and $4$ (for negative arguments) only. This is because the range of $\arctan(x)$ is $\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$.

Here, taking $\arctan\left(-\sqrt{3}\right)$ gives us $-\frac{\pi}{3}$, so we add $\pi$ in order to get the angle in the second quadrant - $\frac{2\pi}{3}$.

Similarly, if both sine and cosine are negative, then the angle desired is in quadrant $3$, but since tangent is positive, the angle given by taking the actangent would be the quadrant $1$ angle, so you'd have to add $\pi$ to get the quadrant $3$ angle.

Comment: Thank you so much! Completely understand, I think it was lack of sleep yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\cos\theta=\frac12$ has acute root $\frac{\pi}{3}$, $\cos\theta=-\frac12$ has obtuse root $\frac{2\pi}{3}$. By $\sin(\pi-x)=\sin x$, we've also satisfied $\sin\theta=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$.

Comment: Thank you very much